# How to place an invisible input in each cell of an table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have this table that should look like this:

[image]

With the cells value changeable.

But inside each cell I want a `<input type="number">` with the cell value, and if I click it, I can modify the value.

The most important part is the style. How can I style the table with the input's to keep the same looking?

Now, each cell is constituted by:

```
<td>
    <div>
        <p>Cell title</p>
        <p onclick="change(this);">Cell value</p>
    </div>
</td>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add inputs to table cells...here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/SA7He/)

```
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with an html5 solution, you can use the contenteditable attribute:

http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

The browser support is actually surprisingly quite good. Even IE supports it.

http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/#browser-support

Basically doing this:

```
<div>
    <p>Cell title</p>
    <p contenteditable="true">Cell value</p>
</div>
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BgUrx/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a visible input without borders or background, it would feel like a 'normal' text but editable.